# Writing a recursive function to run up a chain of relationships

Tags: python, recursion

I am investigating a list of funding bodies, and I need to sort out which are United States federal funders and keep them. I am using the [ROR ID](https://ror.org/) of each funder to identify it and the ROR REST API to return details about each.

My question is how to approach writing a function to recursively investigate each `parent` relationship of a funder, and each `parent` of *that* funder, and so on, chasing it all the way up the chain until it arrives at the top where I can see if the top level is "Government of the United States of America" (https://ror.org/02rcrvv70) or not.

As an example, let's look at the Delaware Space Grant Program ([API response](https://api.ror.org/organizations/010jszw77)). This is two levels removed from the top USGov't, which I can see by manually clicking: Delaware -> NASA -> US Govt.

The recursive function should try the first `parent` relationship it finds (in this case, NASA), look that ROR ID up in the API (https://api.ror.org/organizations/027ka1x80), see if it has parents, if it does, investigate those, and so on. If it turns out this did not provide a path up to USGovt, come back and try the next `parent` (so in this example, if NASA turned out to be a dead end, come back and try a path through the University of Delaware).

[image: ROR API response with relationships field marked]

I am trying to think this through, but getting overwhelmed at the sheer number of possible branches. Each time the program selects a parent to investigate, it will also come across other parents from the next funder that could be an alternative branch.

How can I ensure it looks through all the possible branches thoroughly? How can I keep track of which bottom-level funder we're looking at (NASA vs. UD in this example) and come back to try the next one?

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.ror.org/organizations/010jszw77'
api_response = requests.get(url)
parsed_response = api_response.json()

num_relationships = len(parsed_response['relationships'])  # 2 relationships in this example, both parents
print(f"Found {num_relationships} relationships")

for i in range(0, num_relationships):
    if(parsed_response['relationships'][i]['type']) == "Parent":
        print("parent")
        if parsed_response['relationships'][i]['label'] = "Government of the United States of America":
            USFF = True
        else:
            run_up_chain_to_USGovt(parsed_response['relationships'][i]['id'])
            #kick off recursive run up the chain
    else:
        1 #not a parent, do nothing


def run_up_chain_to_USGovt(rorid):
    
    # get passed a ROR ID
    # see if it has a parent of USGovt
    # if not, investigate a parent and so on
    
    local_url = 'https://api.ror.org/organizations/' + rorid
    local_api_response = requests.get(local_url)
    local_parsed_response = local_api_response.json()
    
    # local_parsed_response['relationships'] is a new list. Have to keep track of which index we're on
    # if the first parent isn't USGovt, try the id of that one. Call run_up_chain_to_USGovt again

    #eventually, if no more parents
        #if local_parsed_response['id'] == https://ror.org/02rcrvv70   # USGovt
           # Found a path to top level USGovt
        #else:
           # No path to USGovt 
           # Go back to the start and try a different parent
    
    return
```

Comment: "The recursive function should try the first parent relationship it finds (in this case, NASA), look that ROR ID up in the API, see if it has parents, if it does, investigate those, and so on." That sounds like a [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: Wikipedia has an example of a recursive solution. Their recursive solution also checks whether it has seen a particular organization before, and if so, it doesn't search it again. This is necessary if it is possible to have two organizations A and B where both A funds B and B funds A. I don't know if that occurs in your dataset. If not, you can skip the stuff about labeling vertexes as discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're "overwhelmed at the sheer number of possible branches" and ask how to "ensure it looks through all the possible branches thoroughly".

This is exactly the point of writing a recursive solution. It's good for searching through very large collections systematically with relatively short and simple code, and if you write it well, it will eventually cover all of them.

There's downsides too, which explains in part why you'd want to do a depth-first search here, to avoid downloading the information for lots of organisations first, but instead checking for resolution as soon as possible - after all you're only interested to know if *any* of the parents have the US govt. as a parent, not all of them, or what number.

In your specific case, another downside may be that many organisations may have the same parent, but your approach will download the data for them every single time. So, you'd probably want to remember whatever you downloaded, in case you run into it a second time (it won't have the US govt. as a parent, otherwise you'd be done already).

It also helps to avoid having mistakes in the code you're trying to improve. Your code has a typo:

```
        # needs ==, not =
        if parsed_response['relationships'][i]['label'] == "Government of the United States of America":
```

And the order of your code means that you're calling the function you defined before it was defined.

Finally, it's unclear what you expect this to achieve:

```
        1  # not a parent, do nothing
```

To do nothing, use `pass`.

Fixing those problems, this is what you had:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.ror.org/organizations/010jszw77'
api_response = requests.get(url)
parsed_response = api_response.json()

num_relationships = len(parsed_response['relationships'])  # 2 relationships in this example, both parents
print(f"Found {num_relationships} relationships")


def run_up_chain_to_USGovt(rorid):
    local_url = 'https://api.ror.org/organizations/' + rorid
    local_api_response = requests.get(local_url)
    local_parsed_response = local_api_response.json()

    return


for i in range(0, num_relationships):
    if (parsed_response['relationships'][i]['type']) == "Parent":
        print("parent")
        if parsed_response['relationships'][i]['label'] == "Government of the United States of America":
            USFF = True
        else:
            run_up_chain_to_USGovt(parsed_response['relationships'][i]['id'])
    else:
        pass
```

One more issue to point out is that `parsed_response['relationships'][i]['id']` actually returns a full URL. As it turns out, the API is forgiving and accepts something like `https://api.ror.org/organizations/https://ror.org/027ka1x80` but it seems to me that `https://api.ror.org/organizations/027ka1x80` would be intended.

What you really want your recursive function to do:

- load the data for an organisation
- for each of its relationships

  - check if it is a parent

    - if so, check if it is the US govt.

      - if so, we're done - the organisation has the US govt. as a parent, return `True`
      - if not, call the recursive function to first check all of *its* parents
      - if the result is `True`, this organisation has it as a grandparent, return `True`
- if we didn't return `True` already, none were the US govt. or had it as a (grand)parent, return `False`

And with caching in mind, instead of "call the recursive function", we should "call the recursive function if we haven't checked this organisation before, it doesn't have the US govt. as a grandparent". And that only works if we save the organisation's ID before returning `False` from anywhere, remembering not to check this again.

In your original code, you load an organisation's details twice, inside and outside the function, but you could just call the recursive function with the original organisation's ID and check the result.

With all that:

```
import requests
from requests import Response


def has_US_govt_parent(org_id: str, visited: list[str] = None) -> bool:
    """
    Returns True if the organization with the given ROR ID has a parent organization
    that is the Government of the United States of America, False otherwise.
    """
    # start with an empty cache
    if visited is None:
        visited = []

    # - load the data for an organisation
    print(f'Loading data for {org_id}')
    url = f'https://api.ror.org/organizations/{org_id}'
    api_response: Response = requests.get(url)
    parsed_response = api_response.json()

    # - for each of its relationships
    # you don't need the number of relationships and index it, you can just loop over the members
    for relationship in parsed_response['relationships']:
        # - check if it is a parent
        if relationship['type'] == "Parent":
            # -if so, check if it is the US government
            if relationship['label'] == "Government of the United States of America":
                return True
            else:
                # assuming that the last part without slashes is the actual ID, there's many ways to do this
                parent_id = relationship['id'].split('/')[-1]
                # - call the recursive function if we haven't checked this organisation before, otherwise no
                if parent_id in visited:
                    grandparent_US_govt = False
                else:
                    print(f'Need to check parents of {relationship["label"]}')
                    grandparent_US_govt = has_US_govt_parent(parent_id, visited)
                # - if the result is True, this organisation has it as a grandparent, return True
                if grandparent_US_govt:
                    return True
        else:
            pass

    # remember we already visited this one, it will always be False
    visited.append(org_id)

    # - if we didn't return True already, none were the US govt. or had it as a (grand)parent, return False
    return False


if has_US_govt_parent('010jszw77'):
    print('010jszw77 has a US government parent')
else:
    print('010jszw77 does not have a US government parent')
```

Output:

```
Loading data for 010jszw77
Need to check parents of National Aeronautics and Space Administration
Loading data for 027ka1x80
010jszw77 has a US government parent
```

Note that, if you were to perform such a search frequently, you would probably want to build a quick lookup table, and update it periodically instead of making all these API calls every time. Or, if you make many such searches from a single program, keep `visited` at least so that subsequent searches will be a lot faster.

Keeping track of `visited` outside the function, and making use of it more cleanly to check if the organisation was visited already:

```
import requests
from requests import Response


def has_US_govt_parent(org_id: str, visited: dict[str, bool] = None) -> bool:
    """
    Returns True if the organization with the given ROR ID has a parent organization
    that is the Government of the United States of America, False otherwise.
    """
    # start with an empty cache
    if visited is None:
        visited = {}

    # just check it here, and we're done
    if org_id in visited:
        return visited[org_id]

    # - load the data for an organisation
    print(f'Loading data for {org_id}')
    url = f'https://api.ror.org/organizations/{org_id}'
    api_response: Response = requests.get(url)
    parsed_response = api_response.json()

    # assume we won't find the US govt.
    result = False

    # - for each of its relationships
    # you don't need the number of relationships and index it, you can just loop over the members
    for relationship in parsed_response['relationships']:
        # - check if it is a parent
        if relationship['type'] == "Parent":
            # -if so, check if it is the US government
            if relationship['label'] == "Government of the United States of America":
                result = True
                break
            else:
                # assuming that the last part without slashes is the actual ID, there's many ways to do this
                parent_id = relationship['id'].split('/')[-1]
                # - call the recursive function
                print(f'Need to check parents of {relationship["label"]}')
                if has_US_govt_parent(parent_id, visited):
                    result = True
                    break
        else:
            pass

    # remember we already visited this one, it will always be False
    visited[org_id] = result

    # - if we didn't return True already, none were the US govt. or had it as a (grand)parent, return False
    return result


visited = {}

if has_US_govt_parent('010jszw77', visited):
    print('010jszw77 has a US government parent')
else:
    print('010jszw77 does not have a US government parent')

print('Data for these organisations were retrieved: ', visited)
```

This improves things by not just keeping track of organisations that already returned `False`, but just remembering all the results in a dictionary cache and reusing that cache for consecutive calls.

Now, you can also:

```
visited = {}
orgs = ['01s3dpm97', '010jszw77', '028b18z22']
for org in orgs:
    print(f'Checking {org}')
    if has_US_govt_parent(org, visited):
        print(f'{org} has a US government parent')
    else:
        print(f'{org} does not have a US government parent')
print('Visited: ', visited)
```

Output:

```
Checking 01s3dpm97
Loading data for 01s3dpm97
Need to check parents of University of Alabama in Huntsville
Loading data for 02zsxwr40
Need to check parents of University of Alabama System
Loading data for 051fvmk98
01s3dpm97 does not have a US government parent
Checking 010jszw77
Loading data for 010jszw77
Need to check parents of National Aeronautics and Space Administration
Loading data for 027ka1x80
010jszw77 has a US government parent
Checking 028b18z22
Loading data for 028b18z22
Need to check parents of National Aeronautics and Space Administration
028b18z22 has a US government parent
Visited:  {'051fvmk98': False, '02zsxwr40': False, '01s3dpm97': False, '027ka1x80': True, '010jszw77': True, '028b18z22': True}
```

Comment: WOW! Holy moly. Thank you so much. I'm going to pick through this code line by line to see how it's done.

I posted this and then drove somewhere, and during that time I realized I don't need to be testing every funder every time so I should keep track of what's already run. It's good to see that confirmed in your approach. I also had a question on `visited` being visible outside the function but see you already fixed that in the last block.

There are still things I don't understand [`api_response: Response = requests.get(url)` vs `api_response = requests.get(url)`] but I will work on it.

Comment: Good pickup - `api_response: Response` was only there to help my editor know about the type and avoid a warning, but the reason I had that there disappeared from the code. It's not wrong, but you correctly picked up on that being superfluous in the version of the code I ended up sharing as a solution. You can use `api_response = requests.get(url)` and lose the `import` as well.

Comment: I think I found a problem. The final set of code provided only checks the *first* parent it finds in the specified org, and never returns to test any subsequent parents if the first one doesn't lead to the USGovt. Example is `01s3dpm97`. This has two parents - the first is UAlabama (correctly finds no path), but the second is NASA (has a path but is not found). The code returns `01s3dpm97 does not have a US government parent`. EDIT: nevermind, I see the second NASA is of type `Related`, not `Parent`.

Comment: ID `010jszw77` has two parents, NASA and University of Delaware. I modified the code to look for "University of Delaware" instead and it successfully found it, even though it was the second parent listed.

Comment: And ID `00fe3cc74` has two parents, Iowa State University and NASA. Correctly identifies NASA through the second parent.

Answer (score 1):

My algorithm works like this:

- I treat the organizations as node in a tree, each node has parent-, sibling-, or related nodes
- Each node has a node ID, e.g. '010jszw77'
- The meat of this algorithm is in function `has_usgov_as_parent()`. Given a node ID, it will return true if the node itself or any parent up the tree is a US gov node.
- I believe I put enough comments in `has_usgov_as_parent()` to make the code easy to understand.

Here is a sample run where a node has US gov up the chain:

```
Testing node Delaware Space Grant Consortium, id=010jszw77
Testing node National Aeronautics and Space Administration, id=027ka1x80
Direct parent of National Aeronautics and Space Administration is US Gov
Up-the-chain parent of Delaware Space Grant Consortium is US Gov
Found it now
```

Here is another sample where not found:

```
Testing node Alfred I. duPont Hospital for Children, id=00jyx0v10
Testing node Nemours Children's Health System, id=01mzw6m29
Does not have US Gov as parent: Nemours Children's Health System
Does not have US Gov as parent: Alfred I. duPont Hospital for Children
Not found
```

Here is the code:

```py
import requests

SESSION = requests.Session()
USGOV_ID = "https://ror.org/02rcrvv70"


def get_id(url):
    """Given a node ID or a URL, return the ID part."""
    return url.split("/")[-1]


def get_info(node_id):
    """Given a node ID, (e.g. 01sbq1a82), return the details."""
    node_id = get_id(node_id)
    url = f"https://api.ror.org/organizations/{node_id}"
    response = SESSION.get(url)
    return response.json()


def has_usgov_as_parent(node_id):
    """
    Returns True if this node, or any parent up the chain is a US Gov,
    return False otherwise.
    """
    node = get_info(node_id)
    print(f"Testing node {node['name']}, id={get_id(node['id'])}")

    if node["id"] == USGOV_ID:
        # Case: This node is US gov
        print("Found it")
        return True
    
    for sub_node in node["relationships"]:
        if sub_node["type"] != "Parent":
            # This is not a parent, skip
            continue

        if sub_node["id"] == USGOV_ID:
            # This parent node is a US gov
            print(f"Direct parent of {node['name']} is US Gov")
            return True
        
        if has_usgov_as_parent(sub_node["id"]):
            # This parent node is not a US gov, but somewhere
            # up the chain, we found a US gov node
            print(f"Up-the-chain parent of {node['name']} is US Gov")
            return True

    print(f"Does not have US Gov as parent: {node['name']}")
    return False


node_id = "00jyx0v10"
if has_usgov_as_parent(node_id):
    print("Found it now")
else:
    print("Not found")
```